Selenium not getting the information from VBA "NoSuchElementError"
This is my first StackOverflow post ever.
I'm trying to copy data from a table in a web, the problem is that is my first time using Selenium. I was trying to use FindElementByClass but it says that it doesnt exist.
My code is this:
URLtexto = "https://www.scopus.com/sources.uri" '"https://www.bing.com/search?q="
Dim dd As Variant

Dim bot As New WebDriver
    bot.Start "edge", "https://www.google.com"
    bot.Get URLtexto
    bot.Wait 5000
    
    dd = bot.FindElementByClass("table").FindElementByClass("lightGreyBorderBottom")(1).Text

The snipped HTML from the web that I'm trying to copy is this:
<table class="table main-table" id="sourceResults" role="grid" aria-readonly="true">
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" id="1" class="lightGreyBorderBottom">
      <td style="width: 6%;">
        <div id="28773div" class="checkbox">
          <input id="source28773" name="selectedSources" type="checkbox" value="28773" onclick="sourceSelection.toggleSourceCheckbox(this.form, this)">
          <label for="source28773" class="checkbox-label">1</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 35%;">
        <a href="/sourceid/28773" title="View details for this source.">Ca-A Cancer Journal for Clinicians</a>
        <div class="sourceListOutwardLinks marginTopHalf"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 11%;">873.2</td>
      <td style="width: 15%;">
        <a href="/sourceid/28773#tabs=1" title="View CiteScore rank and trend for this source.">99%</a>
        <div class="additionalContent"></div>
        <a href="/sourceid/28773#tabs=1" title="View CiteScore rank and trend for this source."><span>1/404</span></a>
        <br>
        <span>Oncology</span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 11%;">92,555</td>
      <td style="width: 11%;">106</td>
      <td style="width: 11%;">95</td>
      <td class="noWidth" style="width: 11%;">167.948</td>
      <td class="noWidth" style="width: 11%;">106.094</td>
      <td class="noWidth" style="width: 11%;">John Wiley &amp; Sons</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" id="2" class="lightGreyBorderBottom">
      <td style="width: 6%;">
        <div id="20315div" class="checkbox">
          <input id="source20315" name="selectedSources" type="checkbox" value="20315" onclick="sourceSelection.toggleSourceCheckbox(this.form, this)">
          <label for="source20315" class="checkbox-label">2</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 35%;">
        <a href="/sourceid/20315" title="View details for this source.">Nature Reviews Molecular Cell Biology</a>
        <div class="sourceListOutwardLinks marginTopHalf"></div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 11%;">173.6</td>
      <td style="width: 15%;">
        <a href="/sourceid/20315#tabs=1" title="View CiteScore rank and trend for this source.">99%</a>
        <div class="additionalContent"></div>
        <a href="/sourceid/20315#tabs=1" title="View CiteScore rank and trend for this source.">
          <span>1/410</span>
        </a>
        <br>
        <span>Molecular Biology</span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 11%;">34,204</td>
      <td style="width: 11%;">197</td>
      <td style="width: 11%;">92</td>
      <td class="noWidth" style="width: 11%;">19.301</td>
      <td class="noWidth" style="width: 11%;">35.91</td>
      <td class="noWidth" style="width: 11%;">Springer Nature</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

I want to copy the full table, in parts, with all the data, but VBA contiues giving me the error "NoSuchElement", "Element not found for Class=lightGreyBorderBottom"
I would appreciate your help.
Best regards.
I've tried differents *.FindElementByXYZ" and it didn't work. I'm not good with Selenium.
I've tried to use FindElementByTag("tr")(0).text and nothing

Try another approach.  First identify the table, then get all rows in the table, then get each row text:
Dim trs As WebElements, tbl As WebElement
Set tbl = bot.FindElementByClass("main-table")
Set trs = tbl.FindElementsByTag("tr")

For idx = 1 To trs.Count
    dd = trs.Item(idx).Text
    'place dd...
Next idx


Thank you so much igittr!!!!,
I did an small change, I've just put:
Set tds = tbl.FindElementsByTag("td")
Because I need all the "td"s in a specific cell.
Your really helped me!
Best regards from Peru :)
Now I will try to click in someplace
